# Is it possible to parse and extract data from a string like { abc{content}xyz{content}randomtext{content} } without escaping the brackets

Tags: javascript, c#, string, algorithm, parsing

I have string like this which is easy to parse with a normal **regex**:

```
 { a{some text} b{someOther text} xyz{some other text} randomName{ more text} }
```

Is it possible to correctly parse the **name** of the groups (a,xyz,randomName) and the **content**? 
The result should be :

```
(groupName, content)

(a,  some text)
(b, someOther text)
(xyz, some { other broken }  text)
(randomName,  more text)
```

Think about this complicated case where the `{` `}` are part of the content:

```
{ a{ some text { } b{ many brackets  {{{{ }  } xyz{ some { other broken }  text} randomName{ {} } }
```

Note: the solution should not be to escape the { & } characters, but to recognize the groups directly.

The correct parsed data groups should be:

```
(a, some text {)
(b,  many brackets  {{{{ } )
(xyz, some { other broken }  text)
(randomName,  {} })
```

Comment: Javascript or C#? They're *pretty* different languages

Comment: The solution could be in any language, the core is the algorithmic problem.

Comment: `b{ many brackets  {{{{ }  } xyz`=> `b -  many brackets  {{{{`  doesn't make sens why not `b -  many brackets  {{{{ }` ... not mention that why a is not `some text { } b{ many brackets  {{{{ }  } xyz{ some { other broken }  text} randomName{ {}` ... is not parsable

Comment: Sorry, I think the hyphen confuses the answer, I think now is more clear the expected result. Basically is to get the group name and the text inside the brackets. The problem is how you identify the correct brackets and ignore the in-between ones.

Comment: Expected `(b,  many brackets  {{{{ )` or `(b,  many brackets  {{{{ })`?

Comment: Sorry a typo! should be `(b, many brackets {{{{ })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't capture the group name, but I think it extracts the values you expect.

```
string input = "{ a{ some text { } b{ many brackets  {{{{ }  } xyz{ some { other broken }  text} randomName{ {} } }";
input = input.Trim(new char[]{'{', '}'});
var matches2 = Regex.Split(input, "(^|}) ([a-zA-Z]+?)({|$)", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);


Console.WriteLine("-------------------------");
foreach (var m in matches2) Console.WriteLine(m);
Console.WriteLine("-------------------------");
```

### Output

```
-------------------------

 some text { 
 many brackets  {{{{ }  
 some { other broken }  text
 {} } 
-------------------------
```

Note: The empty element is there because:

> If a match is found at the beginning or the end of the input string, an empty string is included at the beginning or the end of the returned array.

Comment: This is brillant! the key here is that the regex targets the group names which we know won't have `{` & `}`  in their names, and then we can easily read the contents.  Alexei example actually is a also valid, because it would result in this:   `(b,  many brackets {)`   & .  `(x, {{{ )`